# Which P&S camera has wide lens, power adapter socket, and PC control via USB?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, point-and-shoot, timelapse, wide-angle, usb

I'm looking for a camera that has all of the following traits :
Wide Lens (28mm)
Socket for external power
Controlled with software via the USB
Cheap (older model ?)

I want to do a time-lapse spanning many months.
I don't need a lot of MegaPixels, but I do need at least 2mp.
And ideas ?

Thanks,

SW

Comment: Will a computer save all of the data, or do you need it to also save it's data? If a computer will save all of the data, just get a webcam, they are usually quite wide angle, easily controlled, and are powered by USB.

Comment: Tried that, I have a very good HD webcam. Image quality is still fairly bad, and during the night its unusable.

Comment: You'll want to add that to your list of requirements, then, because this is likely to be true for a cheap older model digicam as well.

Comment: @mattdm: Really? Can you find a point-and-shoot camera (a real camera, not a mobile phone or webcam) from a reputable camera manufacturer that doesn't have a *much* better low-light performance than a webcam? In a point-and-shoot camera, you have the advantage of a mechanical shutter and long exposures; a webcam has neither of those and low-light pictures are near-useless.

Comment: I dont think so, I have an antique Kodak 3mp, and even that is much better than the webcam. Anything made in the past 3-4 years would do.

Comment: It's really not that hard to find a digicam with abysmal low-light performance. I'll pick something from Olympus. I'm not saying webcams aren't also bad, but a "very good" one will be at least in the same ballpark as a cheap digicam.

Comment: Turns out that very few camera have PC control or SDK,
even Canon stopped adding this feature to it's P&S cameras after the G10.
Sad.

Comment: Why do you want to control the camera via computer? It might help us to help you if you give us a bit more of what you intend to do with this, so we can figure out the best overall solution.

Comment: This is a setup that will take an picture every minute for several months. I need computer control to trigger the camera, and to store the images.

Comment: This feels really close to http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1563/are-there-any-tetherable-compact-cameras now.

Comment: @Shachar: You know, you might get better help if you actually listed *all* your requirements up front rather than to have people pry your requirements out of you one at a time. What is this, information on a 'need to know' basis? ;-) To paraphrase the immortal words of Jerry McGuire, "help *us* help *you*!" At the VERY least, please update your question with the new requirements that have been identified so people who are new to the thread don't have to read every... single... comment... before they have enough data to give an answer. Just sayin'...

Comment: @Jay: You are correct. Some of the issues raised in the comments I did not think about them when formulating the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So,
after digging around all day I found my camera :
Canon S70.
It is the only camera that comes close to the requirement list.
It is around 100$ on ebay.
It does not have a power socket, but there is this :
http://sterlingtek.com/st10-trav---canon-powershot-s70-power-adapter.html

On a side note, one of the reason I always preferred Canon was their 
free software SDK for camera control. Sadly, they have discontinued this
feature after the G10 came out in 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking this one up a bit more, and I think what you really want is a high quality web cam, not the cheap kind that most of us get. I looked around, and found [this article](http://askville.amazon.com/Low-Light-Webcam/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=3119967). The winner seems to be [DIGI INTERNATIONAL 301-9010-01 Watchport/V2 USB Camera](http://amzn.to/eVcBzh). Granted, the article is a few months old, but I would hope it's still decent. This webcam is normally used for sensitive areas, like ATMs, surveillance, etc. The cost is a bit high, but not unreasonable, $142.

EDIT: Based off of your latest requirements, I'm going to change my suggest to the following:

[Olympus Evolt E-500, 8.0 Megapixel, SLR, Digital Camera Body (Black)](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/800750504-USE/Olympus_262060_Evolt_E_500_Digital_Camera.html)
[Olympus 14-45mm f/3.5-5.6 Zuiko EZ Zoom Lens for Olympus Digital Cameras (Four Thirds System)](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/800750504-USE/Olympus_262060_Evolt_E_500_Digital_Camera.html)

Get them together, it's around $300, but I can't see how you are going to get everything you are asking for for less than that. Plus you'll have a DSLR, which'll help you with a lot of things in the future.

I just can't find a better deal around, perhaps someone else will...

Comment: DIGI resolution is 640 x 480, thats too low. I need 1080p.

Comment: You might want to add that to your list of requirements as well then...

Comment: And I have one of Logitech's top range webcams, and its still not good enough.

Comment: I'm looking at over 40K pictures per month on this setup, for 4-6 month. DSLR shutter will not stand it.